# How to Upload images and show in html tables?

Tags: forms, media, files

Programers.
I have some question to ask:
(1)I have create a form to upload image file, the files is located in "public://images".This is my buildForm.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {$form['add_toDb']['foto'] = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => t('foto'),
  '#required'=>TRUE,
  '#upload_location'=>'public://images/',
  '#progress_indicator'=>'throbber',
  '#status'=>FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT,
  '#progress_message'=>'uploading......'
  );
}
public function submitToDbForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
 $foto = $form_state->getValue('foto');
 //$file= file_load($form_state['value']['foto']);
 $foto_url= file_create_url($foto->uri);
 //$foto_url=$foto->getFileUri();
 $entry = array(
 ... 
 'foto' => $foto_url,
 ...  
 )
 $return = UpMeetingDbQuery::insert($entry);
 if ($return) {
  drupal_set_message(t('Created entry @entry', array('@entry' => print_r($entry, TRUE))));}}
```

The Question is :$foto_url is website name,not the path of images;

(2)I want put the files located infomation into database(PostgreSQL).

```
class UpMeetingDbQuery{public static function insert($entry) {
$return_value = NULL;
try {
  $return_value = db_insert('orgwork_upmeeting')
    ->fields($entry)
    ->execute();
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
  drupal_set_message(t('db_insert failed. Message = %message, query= %query', array(
    '%message' => $e->getMessage(),
    '%query' => $e->query_string,
  )
  ), 'error');
}
return $return_value;}}
```

(3)Then, I want the images display in a html table.

```
$headers = UpMeetingFunction::headerTable($header_line);
$results = UpMeetingDbQuery::tableList();

$rows = array();
foreach ($results as $row) {
$rows[] = array_map('Drupal\Component\Utility\SafeMarkup::checkPlain', $row);
  $options[$row['pid']]= 
    array(
    'order_id'            =>  $row['order_id'],
    'name'                =>  $row['name'],
    'foto'                =>  $row['foto'],
```

...
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're building a custom admin form or module, "Upload images and show in html tables" can easily be done using [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) (custom, public forms), [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) (fieldable files) and [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) (custom entity displays).